# WebClient().DownloadString () hangs in C#

Tags: c#, mono, osx-lion

I'm a PHP developer, attempting to teach myself C#. I've got the following test code:

```
//longbow.cs

using System;
using System.Net;

public class LongbowCore {
    //version of the software
    public static string version = "0.1";

    //Text displayed during startup
    public static string init_text = "Longbow v"+LongbowCore.version;

    //API URL base for sessions
    public static string api_url = "http://dev.phyre.im";


    public static void Main(string[] args){

        Console.WriteLine(LongbowCore.init_text);
        var fetch = new WebClient();
        var data = fetch.DownloadString(api_url);
        Console.WriteLine(api_url + " Data: " + data);
    }


}
```

On run, anything after `fetch.DownloadString(api_url)` fails to display. I'm not convinced it's doing anything at all. Commenting that line out (and removing the string from Console.WriteLine) allows it to continue. What am I doing wrong?

If it's relevant, I'm compiling in Mono on OSX Lion.

---

Apologies! So, so sorry - apparently there was a network outage at my VPS host - half my machines were down, including my DNS somehow. I didn't realize. Voting to close my question.

Comment: You might want to look at System.Net.HttpWebRequest (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest) instead of System.Net.WebClient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong.... just that website,  dev.phyre.im    its taking a very very very long time.   Just keep waiting, you will get a timeout exception

Comment: and now it seems to be quick again!  and the code completes with the downloaded page

Comment: Apologies! So, so sorry - apparently there was a network outage at my VPS host - half my machines were down, including my DNS somehow. I didn't realize. Voting to close my question.